# Automatically Installing Software in Windows

Tags: installation, automation

I need a way to automatically install software in a local network. Installation should begin while PC boots through a net installer.

What software do u suggest me to use? I have read about WPKG but didn't tried yet. Are there any good free alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Use The Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2012 Update 1. You would build a custom task sequence that rolls out software. It's free and easy to use, all the scripts all already written. All you have to do is manage a GUI from a MMC snapin.

[image]
**MDT is really nothing more than a GUI to manage custom deployment scripts, create a custom task.**

[image]
**Add as many apps you'd like to install, need to uninstall first? No problem. MDT can handle that!**

[image]
**Installsheild, MSI, you name it, it can be automated with MDT!**

Comment: is it free? can i schedule depoloyment while pc boots?

Comment: it is free, you could kick off the litetouch.vbs file from a logon script. What are you trying to exactly? Is this a AD DS environment?